# C# EPPlus - Sorted insertion of data creates empty chuck of rows

Tags: c#, excel, sorting, insert, epplus

I have an excel file containing information about a product category:

```
FatherId | CategoryId | CategoryLevel | CategoryName
```

I need to build a hierarchy for each category like this:

```
 A.Id
  |
  |__A.FatherId = B.Id
     |
     |__B.FatherId = C.Id...
```

I could cycle multiple times trough the excel file and build the hierarchy. But I find that really inefficient. I decided to split each level (there are up to 9 levels) into different excel files. I do so by inserting every new category id in the right place to create an ordered file.
The problem with my code is that sometimes I "create" some blank rows and I cannot figure out why.

Here's the code that handles this:

```
int integerPosition = 2;
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells["A" + integerPosition].Text))
{
    string parentId = worksheet.Cells["A" + integerPosition].Text.Trim();
    string id = worksheet.Cells["B" + integerPosition].Text.Trim();
    string type = worksheet.Cells["C" + integerPosition].Text.Trim();
    // string subType = worksheet.Cells["D" + integerPosition].Text.Trim();
    string name = worksheet.Cells["E" + integerPosition].Text.Trim();
    string imageId = worksheet.Cells["F" + integerPosition].Text.Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
    {
        throw new Exception($"Id at position B{integerPosition} is empty");
    }

    CategoryLevel level = ParseCategoryLevelFromString(type);

    // If you take a look it might seems that ids are not correctly ordered. 
    // But since some ids are strings and others are numbers we treat both as strings.
    // So, for example, id1: 10000023, id2: 5432 -> id1 < id2, because id1[0] < id2[0]..
    long indexToInsert = FindInsertionIndexDichotomically(
        id,
        position =>
        {
            string requestedId = tempWorksheets[level].Cells["B" + (position + 1)].Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestedId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{integerPosition}] RequestedId at position B{position + 1} is empty");
            }

            return requestedId;
        },
        lastUsedPositions[level]
    );

    // If the cell at index indexToInsert is empty there's no need to add any row
    if (tempWorksheets[level].Cells["B" + (indexToInsert + 1)].Value != null)
    {
        tempWorksheets[level].InsertRow((int)indexToInsert + 1, 1);
        Utilities.LogInfo($"[{level}] Inserted row at position: {indexToInsert + 1}", LogFilePath);
    }

    tempWorksheets[level].SetValue("A" + (indexToInsert + 1), parentId);
    tempWorksheets[level].SetValue("B" + (indexToInsert + 1), id);
    tempWorksheets[level].SetValue("C" + (indexToInsert + 1), name);
    tempWorksheets[level].SetValue("D" + (indexToInsert + 1), imageId);

    Utilities.LogInfo($"[{level}] Written category ({id}) at row: {indexToInsert + 1}", LogFilePath);

    // Update the number of element inserted
    lastUsedPositions[level]++;
    integerPosition++;
}
```

And here's the code for `FindInsertionIndexDichotomically`:

```
private static long FindInsertionIndexDichotomically<T>(T target, Func<long, T> getElementAtIndex, long count, Func<T, T, int> customComparison = null) where T : IComparable
{
    Func<T, T, int> compare = customComparison ?? ((arg1, arg2) => arg1.CompareTo(arg2));

    #region Boundary condition

    // The collection is empty
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // The element to insert is smaller or equal then the first element
    if (compare(target, getElementAtIndex(0)) <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // The element to insert is grater or equal then the last element
    if (compare(target, getElementAtIndex(count - 1)) >= 0)
    {
        return count;
    }

    #endregion

    // ReSharper disable once ConvertToLocalFunction
    Func<long, long, long> innerBinarySearch = null; // Do not collapse this line with a direct assignment,
                                                    // otherwise _inner_bynarySearch cannot call itself

    innerBinarySearch = (left, right) =>
    {
        // If the collection is odd we will eventually have left == right
        // If the collection is even we won't have left == right, but right will be smaller then left
        if (right <= left)
        {
            return compare(target, getElementAtIndex(left)) <= 0 ? left : left + 1;
        }

        long relativeCenter = left + (right - left) / 2;                

        int comparisonResult = compare(target, getElementAtIndex(relativeCenter));

        // The element is already present at relativeCenter
        if (comparisonResult == 0)
        {
            return relativeCenter;
        }
        // The element is to be inserted between left and relativeCenter - 1 (relativeCenter - 1,
        // we already checked the centered positon
        if (comparisonResult < 0)
        {
            return innerBinarySearch(left, relativeCenter - 1);
        }

        // The element is to be inserted between relativeCenter - 1 and right (relativeCenter + 1,
        // we already checked the centered positon
        return innerBinarySearch(relativeCenter + 1, right);
    };

    return innerBinarySearch(0, count - 1);
}
```

After this operation I get a sorted excel file, but sometimes I get some chunks of empty row (I checked and they have no content. The source file has no gaps. I cannot understand why.
Thanks